# Centralise image on range slider

Tags: html, range

I have a line of 10 vertical range sliders with an image on top to look like an audio mixer.  The problem is the image moves from left to right depending on the size of the window.  Could someone look at my HTML code on this website and tell me what I am doing wrong ?   Thanks in advance.

http://inposesynth.000webhostapp.com/